# Task scheduler and vbs using a user account

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a vbs script to run with regular user rights.  The script runs fine when logged in as the user, but when I try to run the script from the task scheduler as "Run whether user is logged on or not", it gets stuck on the following line:

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

I have tried running it with "Run with highest privileges" checked and unchecked.  I am running the program from task scheduler as:

```
program/script: "c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe"
arguments: "test.vbs"
start in: c:\
```

Here is the full code:

```
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
set tfo = fso.createTextFile("c:\123.txt")
tfo.writeline("1")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
tfo.writeline("2")
tfo.close
```

output when ran as "Run only when user is logged on":

```
1
2
```

output when ran as "Run whether user is logged on or not":

```
1
```

additionally, the task will run correctly as "Run whether user is logged on or not" when using an admin account, but I cannot use an admin account as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant the user the "Log on as a batch job" privilege. This can be done either via GUI:

- start `gpedit.msc`
- navigate to *Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local Policies → User Righst Assignment*
- double-click "Log on as a batch job" privilege
- add the user account
- click "OK" and close `gpedit.msc`

or on the commandline:

```
ntrights +r SeBatchLogonRight -u domain\username
```

`ntrights.exe` is part of the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657), but works on Windows 7 too. You don't have to install the whole package. Instead you can use e.g. [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) to open/unpack the `rktools.msi` inside the `rktools.exe`.

**Edit:** Since you already did that, the issue is probably that the script can't spawn a GUI application, because you don't have an interactive desktop when the user isn't logged on. Try adding some debugging code to your script:

```
...
On Error Resume Next
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
If Err Then tfo.writeline Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
On Error Goto 0
...
```

A test-run of this code snippet gave me a "permission denied" error. Apparently limited users cannot create an IE instance in a scheduled task.

That said, what are you trying to achieve with the Internet Explorer object? Using an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835871/1630171) might be a better approach for background tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I had already added that.  I probably should have explicitly added that to my question...

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, let me address your questions first:

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, let me address your questions first:
"the issue is probably that the script can't spawn a GUI application", if that were the case, then wouldn't it fail when trying to run the same code with admin credentials?
"what are you trying to achieve with the Internet Explorer object", I'll admit my vbs experience is very limited, and if I had a choice, I would not have done this script in vbs, that said, all I am trying to do is search a webpage for a new virus definition, this worked as admin so I didn't really look into any alternatives, I'll give your XMLHttpRequest a try.

Comment: A test-run with the abovementioned debugging instructions gave me a "permission denied" error. Apparently limited users cannot create an IE instance in a scheduled task.

Comment: Hmm, well that doesn't make sense to me since it is able to run the line after creating the IE instance, I would have expected it to stop executing once it had the error since I didn't have "on error resume next". Either way, I believe you have solved my problem, should I mark your answered as accepted now or did you want to edit your post before I mark it accepted (I'm not sure if it will lock your answer if I accept it as the answer). I wish I was able to find more documentation online for vbs so that I wouldn't have had to bother anyone, but regardless thank you for your extensive help.